# How do I export a baked texture?

Tags: image, texture-baking

I'm new to blender and I'd like to bake my material into a texture in order to export it to GLTF.

Once baked, I do not know where the "baked" texture is, how to visualize it and how to export it out. I could not find any relevant documentation for Blender 2.8.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have baked your texture, you can view it in the image editor.

1. In the image editor select the baked map.
2. Click the button next to the baked image to save it anywhere you like.

[image]

I'm not sure this was the answer you were looking for, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the Image Editor and use the Image menu (or hit Alt S from the Image Editor):

[image: demo pic]